# How can I abstract out or remove this dependency

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I have a 3nf db. In it, there is a series of two tables which are part of a larger chain of dependencies. These two tables (A and B) are giving me problems with regards to enforcing referential integrity.

```
Table A
int AId //primary key
string Name
date Date
int BId //foreign key

Table B
int BId //primary key
string Name
string Description
int CId //foreign key

Table C
int CId
string HowTo
```

*These tables are partial as an example, please see below for an explination:*

Table C holds information of how to make FooBars. When a FooBar is made Table B records the actual way the FooBar was made for tracking and QA purposes.  Once a FooBar has been made, and its data of how it was made filled out in Table B, Table A then will hold a new FooBar along with the information from Table B through the foreign key BId.

My problem is this, sometimes as an outlying case, a FooBar needs to be able to come into the system *without* having been made (basically as an import). However, because of poor design this is not possible without having (in this example) a correlating entry in table B to ensure that the foreign key in Table A is valid and not breaking referential integrity.

The approach I was thinking of taking was to place another table between A and B.

```
Table AB
int ABId //primary key
int BId //foreign key
int AId //foreign key
```

The reason is that multiple FooBars can be made from one entry in Table B, meaning that this change could result in:

```
Table AB

ABId  BId  AId
1     2    6
2     2    7
3     2    8
4     3    9
5     3    10
```

A) **Is there a different approach** I should use to remove this dependency so that records can be added to Table A without needing to satisfy a foreign record in Table B?

B) Is making the change suggested going to slow down queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make `A.BId` able to contain `NULL`, and set it to that for `B-less` A's. `NULL`'s don't participate in the foreign key.

Comment: This is the approach I would like to take. However, this then requires logic to ensure that queries aren't made against the null key. Also, isn't having null foreign keys a violation of referential integrity?

Comment: Queries can be made against NULL, surely, in what possible scenario do you expect `any condition = NULL` (which outcome would be.. `NULL`)? And no, it doesn't violate it, it is a tool that _helps_ dealing with instances like you have at this point.

Comment: Trying to access data from included records where the foreign key was null will result in an exception - so in that scenario. Moreover, referential integrity requires there to be a **valid** reference from all foreign keys.

Comment: First of all, 'included records' smells like you need to alter you application logic to allow a non-related record (but I see no reason why `SELECT * FROM B WHERE id=null` shouldn't be allowed to return 0 records), not the database. Referenial Integrity requires every _value_ to be valid, and `NULL` is by definition _not a value_ but the absence of it. However, take or leave this answer, this is how it usually is done, but you are free to come up with another clean, easily maintainable way.

Comment: See [this for instance](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/server1/referential_integrity.htm): _"no value in the foreign key except NULL should ever exist unless the same value exists in the primary key. A foreign key may be NULL; "_

Comment: That seems to refer to a specific set of referential integrity rules. Overall, there does not seem to be enough consensus on this topic as I read an MSDN article stating not to use NULL, wiki says not to, IBM says as long as the RI is consistent, and a couple others like your link which say NULL is valid. I am not entirely sure if there is one right way, but would rather not use NULLs in that fashion. Do you have any other suggestions that come to mind aside from allowing A.BId to contain NULL?

Comment: The `NULL` just alters the relationship. With `NOT NULL` you _require_ an `1:1` relationship (any A _must_ have a B). Wit `Bid` as `NULL`-capable, you have an `1:0-1` relationship: an A _may have 0 or 1 B_. That last part sounds what you want. Without a link to 'an MSDN article', I cannot tell you why what's there does not apply to your case. And no, I don't have, or have ever needed, another solution.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292166(v=vs.71).aspx - "Referential integrity means that the foreign key in any referencing table must always refer to a valid row in the referenced table.". if this is the only solution you are aware of, then thanks for the input.

Comment: One click away from the article is [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933118(v=sql.80).aspx) at the bottom, which literally states: _"When a FOREIGN KEY constraint is added to an existing column or columns in the table, Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2000 by default checks the existing data in the columns to ensure that all values, except NULL, exist in the column(s) of the referenced PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint. "_ But it you believe that to be a Bug rather then by Design, I guess we're done here indeed.

Comment: Neither, that refers to a composite foreign key when all keys are already in compliance of the referential integrity constraints. In that case, NULL would not affect a composite key because the reference was already valid.

Comment: The word `composite` is NOT in there, and by saying _'all keys are already in compliance'_ and MSDN sating _'a NULL may be in there'_ I conclude a NULL is valid. But let's end this, we're both to stubborn to budge, I don't see us reaching any kind of consensus, so I'll leave it here.